# setActiveItem and Transaction with Sencha & Phonegap

Tags: database, transactions, cordova, web, extjs

I am programming an application with Phonegap & Sencha Touch for Android.
I have a problem with the setActiveItem method of Sencha Touch and dbtransaction of Phonegap.
Here a simple example of my problem :

The function ALWAYS alert 'OK', but the application crashes on the setActiveITem method.

(without the setActiveItem, it works perfectly, and out of the db.transaction function, setActiveItem works perfectly)

I don't understand why ...

```
db.transaction(
    requestFunction, 
    function(err){
        alert("Error processing SQL: "+err.code);
    },
    function(){
        alert('ok');
        viewport.setActiveItem('home');
    );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is hard to know exactly the problem without more code, but I would say it is either because:

- viewport is undefined, so it is trying to call setActiveItem on something that doesn't exist
- viewport is not what you think it is, which is unlikely
- or a card with an id of `home` does not exist.

To help debug the issue, I suggest you set lots of alert()'s and figure out of `viewport` actually exists, and if it does, then check of `home` exists. If they both do, perhaps try setting the active item somewhere else in the code.